# Do finalizers run while the world is stopped?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, thread-safety, clr, finalizer

I need to free an unmanaged resource in cases where Dispose() wasn't called. However, the operation to free the resource is not thread-safe; it must not run concurrently with the main thread. Is it safe for me to free this resource from a finalizer?

Comment: you aren't guaranteed of anything - you should use `IDisposable`.

Comment: "in cases where Dispose() wasn't called"